# Create CSS3 ring with 60% a different colour

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a ring like the one below:

[image: CSS3 ring]

There will be 5 or six on the page, each with a different level of the orange section going around the ring.

eg. 2 may have 50%, 1 has 30%, 1 has 80%, 1 40%

I can get the orange to be either 25%, 50%, 75%, 100% by following this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="arc arc_start"></div>    
    <div class="arc arc_end"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin:20px;
}
.arc {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:100%;
    border:1px solid;
}
.arc_start {
    border-color:transparent red red red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arc_end {
    border-color:red red red transparent;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(75deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(75deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(75deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(75deg);
    transform: rotate(75deg);
}
```

from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJXwZ/2/)

As its just adding colour to the border of the elements, but this doesn't really help me achieve my goal.

I could probably do this is canvas, but wanted to see if possible not using canvas.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: I read [this blog post](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-ajax-loading-icon/) on a similar subject recently, which might help. It is more for creating an AJAX loader but the shape is similar to what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that you almost have your answer.
You could use `pseudo-element` and `rotate` to hide/show portion of borders to draw in between 0,25,50,75 and 100% overlapping borders by borders.

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/JzmiE

```
div {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border:solid 5px black;
  background:#159;
  border-radius:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:200px;
  color:white;
  font-size:2em;
}
div:before,div:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:-5px;
  left:-5px;
  border:solid 5px transparent;
  height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
  border-radius:inherit;
}
.c30, .c40, .c50 {
  border-left-color:tomato;
  border-bottom-color:tomato;
}
.c30:before {
  border-left-color:black;
  transform:rotate(18deg)
}
.c40:before {
  border-bottom-color:tomato;
  transform:rotate(54deg)
}
.c80 {
    border-color:tomato;
  border-right-color:black;
}
.c80:before {
  border-left-color:tomato;
  transform:rotate(54deg)
}
body {background: #456;}
```

and html

```
<div class="c30">c30</div>
<div class="c40">c40</div>
<div class="c50">c50</div>
<div class="c80">c80</div>
<p>i.e. calculate rotation needed : 30%-25% = 5% of 360deg equals 18deg to increase rotation of one border to add those 5.%</p>
```

Comment: You should show some of that code in your answer here (links dies from time to time). +1. Nice take

Comment: On from this, how would I get the red section to start from the top and go round 30%, 50% etc?

Comment: you could use border-top as a start and rotate main div so it sets visually on midlle-top of circle , just updated demo : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/JzmiE